# Notation question $Aut_{Modk}(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

What is $Aut_{Modk}(A)$ if A is a finite generated algebra, k is a field?

Is it a group of automorphisms of A as a vector space over k or what?

Comment: Yes.  "Modk" should refer to the category of k-modules (k-vector spaces).

Comment: Usually that notation is used for the automorphism group of $A$ as a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

CW answer to push it out of unanswered queue:

"$Modk$" should refer to the category of $k$-modules ($k$-vector spaces).